# Custom Javascript Functions not working when used alongside Bootstrap 4 Input Tagging Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tagging

I am using [Bootstrap tags input](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Tag-Input-Plugin-jQuery.html) to make tags inside text input in HTML, however, I am unable to use Javascript functions that are triggered when the input is clicked whilst using the tag plugin.

I have the following input in HTML:

```
<input id="js_tags" data-role="tagsinput">
```

Note the:

```
data-role="tagsinput"
```

This is required for bootstrap tagging (similar to when you create tags in stack overflow). The tagging js is all from here: (Bootstrap 4 input tags):

I’m trying to run the following javascript on the same input field when it is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#js_tags").click(function(e){
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

The alert does not fire in the JS when I click in the input. However, if I delete the

```
data-role="tagsinput"
```

from the HTML it works just fine. But naturally, the tagging JS doesn't work.

I’ve tried replacing the jquery listener for inline onclick() commands but I get the same result.

How can I trigger a JS function when using BS4 input tags?

Thanks

Comment: I am not super familiar with that library, but often such kind of plugin mask the input by hiding it and rendering some alternate html. The libraries functions that alter the original inputs value, however, altering an input value with javascript does not trigger a click event. You could try whether the library triggers a change event on your input.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Looking through the  plugin code, it adds a class named bootstrap-tagsinput which I can listen out for. I'll add the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.
Looking through the plugin source code, it adds a class to the input named:

```
bootstrap-tagsinput
```

Based on what user3154108 commented, the plugin may be replacing the HTML. The following therefore works:

```
  $(".bootstrap-tagsinput").keyup(function(e){
    alert("string");
  })
```

Getting values out of the input is a little tricker as the input doesn't appear to have a readable value. Adding the following to the pluggin under the options function is working for me.

```
      self.$container.on('keyup', 'input', $.proxy(function(event) {
          var $input = $(event.target);
          var text = $input.val();
          //do whatever you want with the text here!!!
      })
```

Comment: True, a div class = 'bootstrap-tagsinput' is created but still not working, maybe DIV has no keyup event ;)